# share transaction among several connections

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I wonder is it possible to share single database transaction among several physical connections?

This question is caused by curiosity rather than real task. However I encountered a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497188/plsql-remote-debug-breakpoints-not-working) which I would like to explain. I assumed that connection are different, however I could be mistaken and cause is different.

Comment: Yes, this is second phase commit, mostly known as [XA Transactions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/xa-transactions-2-phase-commit). Still, this is not very recommended due to huge memory dumps to maintain this kind of transactions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What do you mean with 'huge memory dumps'?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I do not have XA resources configured on application server (jboss in my case), that is usual `<local-tx-datasource>`